# Total factor productivity and revenue

Tags: productivity

On page 116 of *The British Industrial Revolution in Global Perspective* Robert Allen writes

> "...the total factor productivity of enclosed farms was 18 per cent
>   higher than that of open fields. If rent accounted for one-third of
>   revenues, then enclosure boosted rent by 64 per cent, for example a
>   rise from 12 shillings to 20 shillings per acre."

Is the 64% rent increase derived from the 18% total factor productivity increase here?  If so, what is the working in detail?

Answer (score 1):

Rent was one third of revenue. Revenue increases by 18%. Assuming this all goes to rent
$$
\frac{18}{100/3} = 54.
$$
Perhaps the 6 instead of 5 is a typo?

Comment: Perhaps.  But 12 to 20 is an increase of 2/3, or 66.6%.